# what kinds of 'resultType' as default alias in mybatis?

Tags: alias, default, mybatis, resulttype

I know that 'resultType' as default aliases use 'int', 'map', 'string', something else.

```
(
 'int' : java.lang.Integer,
 'map' :  java.util.Map,
 'string' : java.lang.String
 ...
 ?????  <- what's that?
)
```

please let me know more default aliases.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

- references : http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeAliases) are the type aliases you are looking for. Also it mentions how you can create your own type alias